# Override require() behavior in node

Tags: node.js

I'm looking to create a permission-based plugin system for a project in Node. For ease of writing, and for other reasons, I'd like to allow myself to call a plugin with:

`var plugin = require('plugin');`

Here's the trick, I want to force `plugin` to use my permissions api system, but I want the plugin writer to be able to do something like:

`var library = require('library');`

What this would require, is the ability to create my own `require()` method, and pass it to the plugin/module so they are using my method without any more work. My method would (primitively) work like this:

`function myRequire (module) {
      if(meetsPermissions) return require(module);
      throw 'You don't have the necessary permissions;
    }`

Is this possible in Node?

Comment: I suggest editing title to "Override require() behavior in node" because you'll want to replace the global require() function with your own. my first try would be: `var _require = require; require = function myRequire(){ ... else _require(arguments)}`

Answer (score 3):

You can override the default loader in [`require.extensions`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions). However, this *is* deprecated so it might be removed from Node.js at any time.

For example:

```
var jsloader = require.extensions['.js'];

require.extensions['.js'] = function(module, filename) {
  if (meetsPermissions(module)) return jsloader.apply(this, arguments);
  throw new Error("You don't have the necessary permissions");
};
```

Some caveats (besides from the deprecation):

- this function will be called for all modules (including dependencies-of-dependencies), so `meetsPermissions()` should be relatively fast
- it doesn't seem to get called for built-in modules (`util`, `http`, etc)

Another possible solution could be running all the code in a sandbox using the [`vm`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module. There are various higher-level modules that offer this, like [`node-sandboxed-module`](https://github.com/felixge/node-sandboxed-module).